# endorsement failure during invoke :"error in simulation: error starting container: \"chaincode\"executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I have been facing an error while trying to invoke `InitLedger` in Hyperledger Fabric. The network downs, ups and the chaincode properly gets deployed.

- Fabric Version: 2.2
- Go: 1.15.6

```
# Command
peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile bc/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n basic --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles bc/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles /root/bc/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'
```

```
# Error Log
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 1af4...: could not launch chaincode basic_1.0:25..: error starting container: error starting container: API error (400): OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: \"chaincode\": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"
```

I would greatly appreciate the solution.

Comment: Could you attach the logs of the two commands in peer below? 1. `peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled` 2.`peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted`

Comment: @myeongkil kim , docker logs ID prints a 28,000 characters long log that is tough to input as a comment.

Comment: What is `docker logs ID`?, is it correct to mean the log according to the `queryinstalled `and `querycommitted` commands?

Comment: Using organization 1
+ peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled
+ res=0
Installed chaincodes on peer:
Package ID: basic_1.0:2507a2f062b86a6140c94b41f6d72cbe54828f0e94508b21096c582ececee8f8, Label: basic_1.0
Query installed successful on peer0.org1 on channel


Chaincode successfully deploys with no error signal. Other success messages include:

Chaincode packaged & Installed - Query installed - Chaincode approved & committed -  Query chaincode definition successful.

Comment: could you also give me querycommitted commands & logs?, in this question. not comment

Comment: Additionally, `queryinstalled` commands and logs for `peer0.org2` are also required.

Comment: In order for you to ask for an answer, you have to present only the facts.
You log says it worked correctly, but there are times when it really doesn't exactly match the intended behavior. I only refer to the user's actions, but only trust the log as a result of the operation and infer the issue.

Comment: Also, if you want a clearer and more accurate answer, I think it would be nice to suggest some information in the question so that you can also find the problem with the correct log.
In other words, rather than just saying that you were working normally, it would be more accurate to say that an object worked because it gave some result according to some command in some part.

Comment: This is a log to verify the result of saying that you worked normally.
It's contradictory to say that you've been working fine, but there's a problem.
If it worked normally, the invoke command should also work normally.

In simple terms, the intent of my question is simple.
This is to check whether the actual chaincode is properly installed in peer0.org1/peer0.org2 through the queryinstalled command. In other words, it is the process of checking whether the location of the chaincode (FileSystemPath, default:/var/hyperledger/production) is properly set.

Comment: In the future, if all of these are well configured, I will check the filesystem in the contianer directly, and additionally check the docker volume and image part.

At the moment your question is too broad to find out exactly where something went wrong, and it was asked so that it couldn't be reproduced, so you'll have to do some debugging yourself to answer. In the end, I have to ask you to try to find problems by dividing, checking, and narrowing down a wide range of the results of the debugging you have done yourself.

Comment: The reason why I spend my time answering is because you asked a question and the philosophy of the SO community is to help. Of course, if you find it difficult and annoying to spend that much time finding your problem, talk. Rather than finding the exact point, I will only present the keywords and directions that need to be confirmed.

Comment: + peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz
+ res=0
submitInstallProposal -> INFO 001 Installed remotely: response:<status:200 payload:"basic_1.0"> 
submitInstallProposal ->Chaincode package identifier: basic_1.0:
Chaincode installed peer0.org1
Install Cc on peer0.org2
org2
+ peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz
+ res=0
submitInstallProposal -> Installed remotely:Cc package identifier: basic1.0:
Cc installed on peer0.org2
Using org1
+ peer chaincode queryinstalled
+ res=0
Installed chaincodes on peer:
basic_1, Label: basic1.0
Queryinstalled on peer0.org1 on channel

Comment: First Half:

querying cc definition on peer0.org1 on channel 'mychannel'
Query committed status on peer0.org1,
+ peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted --channelID mychannel --name basic
+ res=0
Committed cc definition for cc 'basic' on 'mychannel':
Version: 1.0, Sequence: 1, Endorsement Plugin: escc, Validation Plugin: vscc, Approvals: [Org1MSP: true, Org2MSP: true]
Query cc definition successful on peer0.org1 on  'mychannel'
Using organization 2
Querying cc definition on peer0.org2 on 'mychannel'...
Attempting Query committed status on peer0.org2,

Comment: Second Half:

+ peer lifecycle cc querycommitted --channelID mychannel - basic
+ res=0
Committed cc definition for cc 'basic' on 'mychannel':
V 1.0, Sequence: 1, Endorsement Plugin: escc, Validation Plugin: vscc, Approvals: [Org1MSP: true, Org2MSP: true]
Query cc definition successful on peer0.org2 on 'mychannel'

(I had to divide it as it's too long - your comments are valuable to me. Thanks for your patience @myeongkil kim)

Comment: Additional error log information is not a comment, you can edit your question and post it.:)

Comment: If everything worked, it seems that you should check the validity of the chaincode. Among the trouble shooting I was doing, the problem that occurred when it was the same as your error occurred when the chaincode was not working properly. Can you check your chaincode and provide more?

Comment: @myeongkil kim , I found out that the GOPATH was not set properly. After setting GOPATH, now it runs smoothly. Thanks a lot for your cooperation!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the GOPATH was not set properly. After **setting GOPATH along with PATH**, now it runs smoothly.